# Scalaz Functor typeclass special symbols

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalaz, scalaz7, kind-projector

Recently I have come across this Scalaz code (e.g. https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala):

```
def compose[G[_]](implicit G0: Functor[G]): Functor[λ[α => F[G[α]]]] =
    new CompositionFunctor[F, G] {
      implicit def F = self
      implicit def G = G0
    }
```

What is the meaning/purpose of the type expression inside the "Functor", i.e. λ[α => F[G[α]]]? Sofar, I have seen just type aliases like e.g. in http://like-a-boss.net/2014/09/27/type-lambda-in-scala.html

```
new Functor[A, ({ type Alias[A] = Tuple2[X, A]})#Alias]
```

Also, Intellij Idea (14.0.3) cannot resolve the symbol. Scalaz built by sbt outside Intellij and then imported into Intellij. Any idea what can be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is enabled by the `kind-projector` Scala plugin. It allows to write type lambdas in more concise way:

```
Functor[λ[α => F[G[α]]]]
```

Without the plugin it would look like:

```
Functor[({type λ[x] = G[F[x]]})#λ]
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see. Unfortunatelly, I seem to be stuck with Intellij. I have found that plugin is declared as suggested (https://github.com/non/kind-projector) in Build.scala in Project folder of Scalaz.However, this is not eventually reflected in the IDE. Do you happen to have any experience with setting the compiler plugin in Intellij?

Comment: That basically means that one cannot play/develop Scalaz in Intellij Idea. Then, what other ide/editor one can use?